# Sacar valor de un diccionario

Tags: python, flask

Necesito de su ayuda.
Tengo esta función:

```
@app.route('/docs/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])    
def get_docs(name):
    for doc in mydata["documents"]:
        print(doc)
        entityName = doc["name"]
        if entityName == name:
            print(name)
            return jsonify(entityName)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Document Invalid'})
```

Quiero obtener un valor que se encuentra en doc el cual tiene lo siguiente.

```
{'name': 'carta', 'label': 'CARTA', 'uuid': 'e666724a-1d7f-4689-91e0-aa4c79d1e19a'}{'name': 'reglamento', 'label': 'REGLAMENTO', 'uuid': '044c6793-27ba-428e-b649-b172a6a82b83'}{'name': 'pagare', 'label': 'PAGARE', 'uuid': 'ae25fe63-d0af-4704-bdd6-5ab3a9935049'}{'name': 'endoso', 'label': 'ENDOSO', 'uuid': '3397f146-a63e-4d8a-8191-0bc7d86a3f0f'}
```

De acuerdo al valor del name quiero obtener el uuid de cada uno me pueden ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un arreglo con cada una de las entidades.

```
@app.route('/docs/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])    
def get_docs(name):
    names = [doc for doc in mydata["documents"] if doc["name"] == name]
    if len(names) > 0:
        return jsonify(names)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Document Invalid'})
```

Según tu update necesinas unicamente el `uuid`:

```
@app.route('/docs/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])    
def get_docs(name):
    names = [doc["uuid"] for doc in mydata["documents"] if doc["name"] == name]
    if len(names) > 0:
        return jsonify(names)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Document Invalid'})
```

Esto te regresará una lista de str con uuids

```
["e666724a-1d7f-4689-91e0-aa4c79d1e19a" , ...]
```

Comment: Justo si funciona pero ahorita me retorna todo el doc con el name que se esta ingresando, pero de ese doc necesito extraer el valor de uuid. Como puedo hacerlo??Lo que imprime names es lo siguiente:[{'name': 'pagare', 'label': 'PAGARE', 'uuid': 'ae25fe63-d0af-4704-bdd6-5ab3a9935049', 'owner': {'id': '1'}}]